# JavaScript: How can you select random elements from an array without allowing duplicates?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looking to randomly select a number from this array WITHOUT duplicates. There can only be two possibilities for each number as shown in the array, select up to a maximum of 6.
This works to select a random number but allows duplicates...

```
const smallNums = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10];

const randomSmallNumArr = smallNums[Math.floor(Math.random() * smallNums.length)];
```

When using the `splice()` method, each time I generate a number based on a random index, it's removed but shows up again in the array the next time a random is generated

Comment: Get rid of the duplicates in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Set` to get the unique items in the array.

```js
const smallNums = [...new Set([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10])]

const randomSmallNumArr = smallNums[Math.floor(Math.random() * smallNums.length)];
console.log(randomSmallNumArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement clearly, You want to generate a non-repeating random numbers from an array of numbers ? If Yes, I added a solution below.

```js
// Input array
const arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10];

// Remove duplicate elements from an array
let uniqueElementsArr = [...new Set(arr)];

// Find out random number from an array
const randomNum = uniqueElementsArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*uniqueElementsArr.length)];

// removing the random number from the existing array so that it should not be replicate.
if (uniqueElementsArr.indexOf(randomNum) !== -1) {
    uniqueElementsArr.splice(uniqueElementsArr.indexOf(randomNum), 1)
}

console.log(randomNum);
```

Comment: The `if` clause is not needed. And since the solution mutates the `uniqueElementsArr ` anyway, one can achieve everything within one task ... `randomNum = uniqueElementsArr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * uniqueElementsArr.length), 1)[0];`

Comment: Yes, you are right! In the code snippet I was not able to call the `uniqueElementsArr` only once. thats the reason it mutates `uniqueElementsArr` everytime snippet run.

Comment: I think it's close but not quite.
Not sure how to rephrase this...

Choose a random number 1 - 10 only allowing a number to be chosen twice. If 20 numbers were chosen you would get [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10] in no particular order.
Would it be easier to start with an empty array, generate a random number, check if the random number has occurred twice, if not, then add it to the array... rather than defining all the possible outcomes and mutating?
Just trying to think it out.